# Deploy with git pull on webserver on /var/www/vhosts

Tags: linux, git, deployment

Can I create with git files owned by root without using root to push?

I use git user to push on the webserver. But /var/www is owned by root or www-data with no write access for other user.

I can pull in an other directory and use "hook/post-receive" but still this hook is executed with the git user...

For the moment I log in the webserver and do a sudo git pull origin. But it will be more efficient if I was hable to do a git pull server from my laptop.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you symlinked something like /home/youruser/pubwww in /var/www? That way, you don't have to mess around with ownership/permissions of files.

Comment: but with symlink I will still have the same problem no?

Comment: Why? Make the symlink to a map owned by the git user. Then push your files to this map as the git user. I don't see how you could run into trouble with permissions that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to give all files to git by way of the `www-pub` group with read permission for everyone—except settings files with the MySQL password.

I push to `/home/git/repository/project` and checkout to `/var/www/project` using `hook/post-receive`.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my comment here as answer, since as far as I know, it will completely fix the problem:

Make a symlink in `/var/www` to a map owned by the `git` user (e.g. `/home/git/www`). Then push your files to this `/home/git/www` map. No problems with permissions anymore.

Comment: it certainly not a bad solution too

Comment: @gagarine Thanks! It should be noted that your solution consume twice the storage space, this might not be a problem with modern hard disk sizes, but it still feel like a waste. With the symlink solution, you don't have that "problem".